# Mysql procedure does not execute as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql 5.7, when I execute this procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE tres()
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxid INT;
    DECLARE x INT;
    SET maxid = 655;
    SET x=1;
    WHILE x<= maxid DO 
        INSERT INTO `forum_topicresponder` (topic_id, username, reply_id) SELECT p.topic_id, p.creator_name, p.id  FROM forum_post AS p  WHERE p.topic_id=x;
     SET  x = x + 1; 
     END WHILE;
END$$
```

I get

> mysql> call tres();
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.49 sec)

However when I execute the INSERT for a certain values inside the loop range:

```
 INSERT INTO `forum_topicresponder` (topic_id, username, reply_id) SELECT p.topic_id, p.creator_name, p.id  FROM forum_post AS p  WHERE p.topic_id=42;
```

I see that the results are inserted without problem.

The table schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_topicresponder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `username` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'na',
  `reply_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=94 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` varchar(16000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creator_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creator_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NA',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6264595 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So what could be wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not clear .What you expect and what happen?

Comment: I expect the loop to go through all the `topic_id`s, fetch the relevant responders for each one and insert them into `forum_topicresponder`. As the single insert query does.

Comment: tested it working fine..it copy all record from forum_post to forum_topicresponder..then what wrong ..?

Comment: i tested here :https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svGMffct6rEStwtX5ho1DL/2

Comment: Thanks for testing. The difference however, is that my  `forum_post` does not have `reply_id` field. I've added the schema. Please see again.

Comment: but in the procedure you did not use forum_post.reply_id , you store the forum_post.id value in the forum_topicresponder.reply_id column ..And it works fine. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svGMffct6rEStwtX5ho1DL/4

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. What have you changed between the two examples? When I try your second example, I still get 0 rows inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of x in the procedure, It might be not matched with your topic_id of the forum_post table.

If topic_id not matched then no data will copy to the forum_topicresponder table.

You need to set the proper value of x, (from min to max) depends on topic_id of forum_post table

Answer (score 0):

Why would you be using a loop for this?  Just do:

```
 INSERT INTO `forum_topicresponder` (topic_id, username, reply_id)
     SELECT p.topic_id, p.creator_name, p.id
     FROM forum_post p
     WHERE p.topic_id <= 665;  -- or use a variable if you prefer
```

Comment: I use loop because topic_ids are not incremented. They are scattered between a range. Also when I try your query I get `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`